# Generating soap service and POJO classes from xsd and wsdl

Tags: maven, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws, wsdl2java

I am creating a soap service by consuming one wsdl and multiple xsd files. The xsd files are included in my wsdl. I have tried with jaxws and cxf plugins using maven. Both the plugins are throwing error/exception while parsing the wsdl.

below is the error from jaxws:

[ERROR] Invalid wsdl:operation "insertSubscriber": its a document-literal operation,    message part must refer to a schema element declaration

CXF dies without throwing any error description.

The jxc framework creates the classes from xsd files but they are of no use because I have to create endpoints manually and the linking of the classes is already defined in my wsdl.

I have also C++ gsoap client which uses the same wsdl and xsds using which I can create my soap service, But I want to migrate my service to a java application. How do I fix the above problem?

wsdl snippet:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="MyDomain/mytypes" location="MyTypes1.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="insertSubscriberRequest">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="insertAddressList" type="mytypes:InsertAddressList"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<wsdl:message name="insertSubscriberRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="insertSubscriberRequest" type="tns:insertSubscriberRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<!--wsdl operation-->
<wsdl:portType name="myService">
    <wsdl:operation name="insertSubscriber">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:insertSubscriberRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:insertSubscriberResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<!--soap operation-->
<wsdl:operation name="insertSubscriber">
    <soap:operation soapAction="MyDomain/mytypes/insertSubscriber"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="MyDomain/mytypes"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="MyDomain/mytypes"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

snippet from MyTypes1.xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="InsertAddressList">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Definition of a list of Account IDs for Insert operation</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="accountId" type="MyType2:sdsAccountId" minOccurs="10" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

snippet from MyTypes2.xsd

```
<xs:simpleType name="sdsAccountId">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Definition of Account ID parameter</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="26"/>
        <xs:pattern value="([0..9]){1,26}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0):

I verified the WSDL file and there was an import error. Actually, It was importing the xsds two times  once in the wsdl:definitions and once in the xsd:schema. removing the import from the wsdl:definitions worked for me,

With wsimport I am facing the same issue, but it is working with cxf.